# Taking a Snapshot of UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I've a custom view controller transition.

Inside the method `animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning)`, upon retrieving the `toVC`, I'm trying to take a snapshot of the navigation bar of the `toVC` but it keeps returning as `nil`.

What do I need to do to retrieve a snapshot of the navigation bar of the coming view controller?